# Executing Linux command in Python with special characters

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, popen

I just want to execute the command `rm /tmp/*.idx` from a python script. I have read that `os.system` is deprecated (IT IS NOT, see the comments), so I'm trying with Popen the following:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('rm /tmp/*.idx'))
proc.communicate()
```

after of course importing `shlex` and `subprocess`, but it doesn't erase the files.

Thanks.

Comment: `subprocess.check_call('rm /tmp/*.idx', shell=True)`

Comment: Where did you read that `os.system()` would be deprecated? The documentation does not seem to say that.

Comment: You can do this without the shell using: `subprocess.check_call(['rm'] + glob.glob('/tmp/*.idx'))`

Comment: the py doc regarding [os.system()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) says that *The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function.*

Comment: I read from some user in other question in this site that `os.system()` was deprecated, I certainly did not read it in the docs. I just trusted the user.Thanks for specifying about it.

Comment: @jordanm: why `check_call` instead of `Popen`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glob patterns are shell syntax. So:

```
subprocess.Popen("rm /tmp/*.idx", shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume the `shlex.split` is not necessary in this case, am I right?

Comment: right. `Popen()` will run it as `/bin/sh -c "rm /tmp/*.idx"`.